# Installing guest additions on android

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

Is it possible? I think it is. Because android is to some extent Linux. Has anyone done this? I will be glad to have any ideas about it. I need it in order to use HGCM.

Answer (score 0):

Guest Additions isn't just a Linux thing, though. It's deeply tied into the X Server and the hardware I/O devices. They are completely different on Android. I really don't think this is going to be possible.

It would require Oracle to write specific Guest Additions for Android.

Comment: I also thought it was impossible. But stumbled upon a quite interesting post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914203/fake-gps-for-android-running-in-virtual-box
As I understand we can't use HGCM without GuestAdditions.